# How can I show a series of images in a splash screen, with a delay between each?

Tags: android

I have implemented a splash screen in my Android app.

In that splash screen, I'd like to have 3 images that display dynamically, one after the other, with a set delay time in between.

How can I do something like this?

Comment: Bagging for source code is not welcome in this community. This site is for help in the problems not for provide source code.

Comment: Sounds more like a job for an animation. Consider trying that instead http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidAnimation/article.html

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code it maybe helpful to you...

You can set your background image resource in runnable1, runnable2 and runnabl3....

```
package com.vc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Splash extends Activity {
private final int FIRST_DELAY = 3000;
private final int SECOND_DELAY = 6000;
private final int THIRD_DELAY = 9000;

private Handler mHandler;
private ImageView mImageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.splash_imgeview);
    mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandler.postDelayed(image1Runnable, FIRST_DELAY);
    mHandler.postDelayed(image2Runnable, SECOND_DELAY);
    mHandler.postDelayed(image3Runnable, THIRD_DELAY);
}

Runnable image1Runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);//First image icon
    }
};
Runnable image2Runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);//Second image icon
    }
};
Runnable image3Runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);//Third image icon
    }
};
}
```